# Why user still bypass the system

Tags: php, authentication

I have this php login codes

```
<?php

   session_start();

   // Connect to server and select databse.
   $link=mysql_connect("localhost","root", "mcl")or die("cannot connect");
   mysql_select_db("mcl",$link)or die("cannot select DB");
   // username and password sent from form
   $fname=$_POST['fname'];
   $password=$_POST['password'];
   // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
   $fname = stripslashes($fname);
      $password = stripslashes($password);
      $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($fname);
      $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
      $sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE fname=('$_POST[fname]') and
      password=('$_POST[password]')";
      $result=mysql_query($sql);
      // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
       $count=mysql_num_rows($result);
       // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
           if($count>0){
           $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['fname'];
           switch($_POST['fname']) {
            case 'root': header("Location: dashboard.php"); break;
            case 'accountant': header("Location: dash_accou.php"); break;
            case 'secretary': header("Location: dash_secretary.php"); break;
       }
       exit;
               }
        else {
        echo "<a href=index.php>Invald username or password <input name=Click here to reload    
       type=button disabled value= <<<Reload></a>";
            }
       ?>
```

Dashboard form address(dashboard.php)

```
      <?php
        session_start();
         if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) ||  $_SESSION['username'] != 'root') {
          header('Location: index.php');
           exit;
        }
     ?>
```

Logout form

```
      <?php   
      session_destroy(); //destroy the session
      header("location:index.php"); 
      exit();
      ?>
```

My aim is to protect user who try to bypass the system, I want when user copy the Url and paste to address bar of page  he/she will be directed to index.php page, But I dont know why when I login and copy address (dashboard.php) then Logout and paste the address on the same browser it open again without Login.

Any help

Comment: Just FYI, you're escaping `$fname` and `$password`, but then using the POST values instead of your escaped values. May want to change that.

Comment: You need to unset session variables when you destroy a session. Just unset any important variable from it.

Comment: Can you add an else on your dashboard.php file and print $_SESSIOn['username'] value ?

Comment: Please read about SQL injections.

Comment: @str: my username is `root'); -- blah`!

Comment: OP: not only should you protect against SQL injection, but you should also change your thinking about passwords. They should be encrypted (PHP has a convenient `crypt` function for this), and instead of searching for them in the DB, you should pull out the password for the found username, use it as the salt when crypt-ing the attempted password, and compare the resulting strings to see if authentication passed or failed.

Comment: How can I add else and to Unsert. Help please

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [PHP-manual](http://php.net/session_destroy):

> In order to kill the session altogether, like to log the user out, the session id must also be unset. If a cookie is used to propagate the session id (default behavior), then the session cookie must be deleted. setcookie() may be used for that.

So you need to delete the cookie also. Code (copy-pasteable) could be found in the manual.

Comment: How to Unset session id,help please

Comment: Read the last sentence of my answer